# How Do I populate the Last Login Date from User object into a custom object/field?

Tags: trigger, custom-object, custom-field, datetime, user-record

Aim – Pull the last login date from the user object into my custom object and populate a particular field

Now I am under the impression that LastLoginDate on the user object is not accessible through formulas in custom objects. The only way that LastLoginDate is accessible is through triggers

****Custom Object**** 
Object Name Mason_Object
API Name    Mason_Object__c

****Field I would like to update is on the mason_object**** 
Field Label : LastLogin
Api Name : LastLogin__c
Data type: Date/Time

I have written the following trigger (see below) however its not pulling through any values. Any ideas why ?

```
trigger lastloginDate on Mason_Object__c(before update) {

User u = [SELECT LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
trigger.new[0].LastLogin__c = u.LastLoginDate;

}
```

Comment: First thing that catches the eye is that your trigger is not very bulk-proof. However, that's not where your question is about..:-)  What do you see in the debug logs if you put a system.debug(u); after the User query?

Comment: Have you tried `after update`? A lot of system fields aren't set until the after transaction, seems strange, but might be worth looking into to

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger lastloginDate on Mason_Object__c(before update) {
User u = [SELECT LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
for(Mason_Object__c c : Trigger.new){
//May want to put some condition checks
c.LastLogin__c = u.LastLoginDate;
}
}
```

But can't this be achieved by some cross object formulas, or are you not able to manipulate an active user?  I don't know I've never done cross object formulas on Users

Update to your comments --

The only way I can think to do it then is so whenever User.oldMap != User.newMap(pseudo), make that kick off your Custom Object and Update it

Comment: Hi Ericssh , unfortunately you are unable to pull back last login date from a formula. So only way to do is it via triggers . I logged into my dev account and replicated your logic how ever the trigger only fires once I need it to fire every-time a user logs in. Fr instance I logged in at 8 and it posted the login date, I signed out of sf and logged back in at 8.20 and the last login date in the object says 8 still.any ideas why ?

Comment: It's because the trigger isn't getting fired again, because it is "before update".. Is there ever any editing done to the page?  Can you give me a Use case?

Comment: Hi, well I all want to do is pull the value in last login date on user object into my new custom object and field. The new object can edited after , but that shouldn't have any bearing on the value being populated . Currently when a user logins in it populates last login date with time stamp. The user can log into sf multiple times and the last login field reflects that's

Comment: Looks good in theory, although to my knowledge a user logging in doesn't cause the user triggers to fire, see the duplicates listed in the question comments.